# How do I make a long binary into an array of 8 bits

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a binary number
`val = 00111010011100011000000010100000000000100000111111010`
i need to convert it to an array with 8 bit elements in it like
`arr = a= [{00111010},{01110001},...]`
is there a simple way to do so in python?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can use bitwise operators `&` and `|` and `>>` and `<<`. This is a really good exercise for you to figure out on your own in order to learn how to manipulate binary data.

Comment: As shown, ``val`` is not a binary number, it is a syntax error. Similarly, ``arr`` is not valid syntax either. Please [edit] your question to clarify what exactly is your input and desired output.

Comment: Ordinarily you could use `struct.unpack`, but that only works for a limited number of integer sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `&` (bitwise AND) operator to extract the last 8 bits and the `>>` (bitwise right shift) to go through the bits:

```
>>> val = 0b00111010011100011000000010100000000000100000111111010
>>> f"{val & 0xff:08b}"
'11111010'
>>> val >>= 8 # shift 8 bits to the right
>>> bin(val)
'0b1110100111000110000000101000000000001000001'
>>> f"{val & 0xff:08b}"
'01000001'
>>> val >>= 8
>>> f"{val & 0xff:08b}"
'00000000'
>>> val >>= 8
>>> f"{val & 0xff:08b}"
'00010100'
>>>
```

Here `0xff == 0b11111111` (8 `1` bits)